# PHP UTF-8, chinese characters escaping

Tags: php, utf-8, escaping

I've a PHP script and MYSQL database.
In this database, I've a lot of entries, in French, English, Chinese, Russian, ...
I would like a php function to return true, if the $var contains other characters of latin (so, russian, chinese, ...)
Euro, Dollars, and specials characters should'nt return false, but true.

I've tried with iconv, mb_check_encoding, but no way, the russian (and other) is converted to : "????????"

Could you help ?
Thanks

Comment: At first you have to make sure, that you're using UTF-8 encoding in the database and when querying the database. Also, you have to use the `mb_` functions in order to handle multibyte strings.

Comment: You should show the code

Comment: Agreed; have a look at http://sscce.org.

Comment: What is the question anyway? is it about detection or about escaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something similar for work, and (with help) came up with this:

```
<?php
function other_chars($str){
    $american = preg_match("/^[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}\p{Common}]*$/u", $str);
    if(!$american){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've able to create a function with the help of Ryan script :

```
function other_chars($str){
    $other = preg_match('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}]/u', $str);
    if(!$other){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks a lot specially to Ryan :)